# SQL Select with multiple AND and OR's goes wrong

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

```
Name | ContactName | Address | City | PostalCode | Country

Alfreds | Maria Anders | Path 57 | Berlin | 12209 | Germany

Ana | Ana Trujillo | Kanne 22 | México | 05021 | Mexico
```

I have pretty the same problem:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country Like '*m*'
Or City Like '*m*'
And PostalCode=05021;
```

Normally I should get Ana.. but I get those datasets. For any reason PostalCode isn't minded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't keep `OR` and `AND` on the same condition level. Keeping your logic you have to use parenthesis for `OR` as below

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE (Country Like '*m*' Or City Like '*m*')
And PostalCode='05021';
```

Comment: Also need to have single quotes around the PostalCode - as a number it will read 5021 and not 05021.

Comment: @Parado you _can_ have them at the same level, but the order of execution is usually different that what's intended.

Comment: @DStanley True I wasn't clarify with it. I polished my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

this is additional variants to already posted variant by `@Parado`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Customers
WHERE   (Country & City) LIKE '*m*'
         AND PostalCode = '05021'
-------------------------------------------------
SELECT  *
FROM    Customers
WHERE   (Country & City & PostalCode) = '*m*05021'
-------------------------------------------------
SELECT  *
FROM    Customers
WHERE   (Country + City + PostalCode) = '%m%05021'
```